# Can not start pulseaudio

Tags: linux, pulseaudio

I have just installed pulse audio on my laptop, however I can not start it.
Here is output when I run command pulseaudio -v

```
................
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: lock: Permission denied
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: lock: Permission denied
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

please help me, thanks very much

p/s: I wonder what core-util.c want to lock and unlock here.

Answer (score 2):

try "sudo service pulseaudio start"

Comment: I don't see any file named /etc/init.d/pulseaudio :(